# Cannot convert from View to Button

Tags: android

Very frustrating problem I have here. I have this code:

```
Button b = findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

And I'm getting this error on it:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert form View to Button

But button1 **is** a button!! In my XML layout document the button has been declared like this:

```
<Button
   android:id = "@+id/button1"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:text = "Next Activity" 
/>
```

And in my R.java:

```
public static final class id {
   public static final int button1=0x7f050000;
}
```

Why I get and error saying that my button is a view when it actually is indeed a button... is a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the view to Button:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

More details at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

In addition, as answered by others, the id is wrong.

Comment: android.R must be packagename.R

Comment: Weird thing is, in one of my projects, I don't need to cast my views, but when I copy the same activity (and layout) into a second different project, I DO need to cast them.  Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

remove `android.R from packages` and import your `R`.

```
import com.companyname.productname.R;
```

and change also button refrence

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: are you sure you removed packages `import android.R` and add your package ? and also change button...

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is here-Button b = findViewById(android.R.id.button1);

Replace the above line by findViewById(R.id.button1);

Comment: I removed the android. from it but I still get the same error?

Comment: maybe ur R.java file may have become corrupted. Start a new project and do it as Button b = findViewById(android.R.id.button1);That will solve your problem